# How can I use LineRenderer to draw a circle depending on radius size around an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawRadiusAround : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    LineRenderer line;

    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        CreatePoints();
    }

    void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        float angle = 20f;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, y, 0));

            angle += (360f / segments);
        }
    }
}
```

Some problems :

- The circle is standing vertical and not like it should be horizontal.
- How can I make that I will be able to change in run time the radius size and the circle width ?
- How can I make that in the editor mode before running the game it will not show the line renderer first
  point near the target object that it should be around ?
- The circle in run time is not completed at the top of it there is a place with some space or a missing
  part.

This screen show is showing the start point or the line renderer in pink near the object before running the game :

[image: Small pink of the line renderer before running the game, How to make that it will not show it ?]

This screenshot is showing the drawn circle of the radius and the linerenderer the script settings in run time :

[image: Drawn circle of radius in run time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the circle horizontal, vary the Z coordinate instead of the Y coordinate:

```
// ...
x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0f, y));
// ..
```

To change the line width, vary the value of [`line.widthMultiplier`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-widthMultiplier.html):

```
line.widthMultiplier = 2f;
```

To change the radius, alter `xradius` and `yradius` then call `CreatePoints` again:

```
xradius = yradius = 10f;
CreatePoints();
```

The circle appears "incomplete" because the ends of the line renderer don't overlap sufficiently. To fix this, go further than 360 degrees by changing the `360f` in the last line to something greater. For instance:

```
// ...
x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0f, y));

angle += (380f / segments);
// ...
```

Comment: I added a global width variable and using this line in the Start and in the CreatePoints method : line.widthMultiplier = width; and then calling the CreatePoints also from inside the Update to be able to make changes in run time and it's working. but is it a good way to call CreatePoints inside the Update ? It will call the for loop all the time.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi I would avoid calling `CreatePoints` in update. Do you need to change the radius in every frame? If so, I would try changing the `localScale` to change the radius, although that might also affect the width.